# Checking out Maven project from SVN in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, subversive, svn-checkout

I have just downloaded and installed the latest Eclipse Juno. I have also installed Maven and SVN through the Eclipse Market Place. The problem I am getting is that when I check-out a project from my SVN repository, the project doesn't get checked out as a Maven project.

I am using Windows 7 x64 OS. Could anyone shed some light on this matter? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How did you try that? Do you have m2e installed?

Comment: My problem exactly. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 8):

With m2e installed, you can right click on the project and:

- "Configure"->"Convert to maven project" (and it will read your pom.xml)
  or
- "Maven"->"Disable maven nature"

I often use both steps (in reverse order) to "reboot" the maven configuration.

Comment: Hi Nickolas, Thanks for you reply. I tried this and it worked however my project now isn't synced with svn. If I go to the 'Team' menu item, in the menu that appears when you right-click on the project, I get nothing where as before I used to get options such as 'update', 'commit' 'sync with repository' etc... Any ideas?

Comment: Did you delete the project and start again, importing as a Maven project?  There's no need to do that - you can add/remove maven & SVN natures at any time.  Try right-clicking on the project and selecting "Team->Share"

Comment: That's one way, but it's not the easiest.  See my answer below

Comment: Basically this answer in addition to answer by @Tomer did the trick for me. For parent pom, "Configure"->"Convert" was enough, for child modules, import was needed. However I don't understand why this won't work as easily as it used to work.

Answer (score 2):

The project doesn't need to be checked out as a maven project.
What you need to do is, after checking out your project ( using the SVN perspective ) go to the Java perspective and **import it as a maven project.**

This will work if your project has a pom.xml file.

[image]

Comment: This works for me except I needed to do extra steps like following:

 1)Right-click on your project, select Maven -> Remove Maven Nature.

 2)Open you terminal, go to your project folder and do “mvn eclipse:clean”
 3)Right click on your Project and select “Configure -> Convert into Maven Project” This is the error to solve this use above steps. 

Credits go to Vipul Gulhane: http://mytechnologythought.blogspot.com/2013/12/an-internal-error-occurred-during.html

Answer (score 1):

You can install a plugin called m2e-subclipse to do that, but it's not currently that support.  You might need to build it yourself.

[Link to m2eclipse-subclipse](https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-subclipse).

Alternatively, what I prefer to do, is check out the project using TortoiseSVN (or a similar client for mac/linux).  Subclipse will still pick up that it is a SVN project, and I'll use m2e to import the project (Import existing Maven project).

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to SVN repository Exploring perspective and checkout the project.
2. Then go to Java perspective, right click the project and select Configure->Convert to Maven project

This works for me in Eclipse Luna.